# OutlinedTextField jetpack compose behind the Keyboard

Tags: android, textfield, android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard

I using Jetpack Compose to make the application UI, but it has some issues: when the next button is clicked on the keyboard it moves the focus to the next `TextField`(Amount), which is fine, but the problem is the `TextField` keeps behind the keyboard, that means the screen animation is not triggering:

How to move the screen to the new next input?

```
@Composable
fun KeyboardSample() {
    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp),

        ) {

        val name = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
        val updateName = { _name: String ->
            name.value = _name
        }

        val amount = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
        val updateAmount = { _amount: String ->
            amount.value = _amount
        }

        TextFieldsToExperiment(
            name = name.value,
            updateName = updateName,
            amount = amount.value,
            updateAmount = updateAmount
        )

    }
}

@Composable
fun TextFieldsToExperiment(
    name: String,
    updateName: (String) -> Unit,
    amount: String,
    updateAmount: (String) -> Unit
) {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val focusRequester = FocusRequester()
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(390.dp))
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = name,
            onValueChange = updateName,
            label = { Text("Name") },
            placeholder = { Text(text = "Name") },
            singleLine = true,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Sentences,
                autoCorrect = true,
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Next
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onNext = {
                focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
            }),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top = 6.dp, start = 0.dp, end = 0.dp, bottom = 6.dp),
        )
        Text(text = "Hello")
        Spacer(Modifier.height(8.dp))
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = amount,
            onValueChange = updateAmount,
            label = { Text("Amount") },
            placeholder = { Text(text = "Amount") },
            singleLine = true,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Sentences,
                autoCorrect = true,
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
                focusManager.clearFocus()
            }),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                .padding(top = 6.dp, start = 0.dp, end = 0.dp, bottom = 6.dp),
        )

    }
}
```

Also, I add some pictures to illustrate better the issue:

UI without keyboard:

[image]

Name Focused

[image]

Amount Focused

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put your **KeyboardSample()** content in a **LazyColumn** like this

```
@Composable
fun KeyboardSample() {
     Scaffold(
          modifier = Modifier
               .fillMaxSize()
               .padding(
                    start = 16.dp,
                    end = 16.dp
               ),

          ) {

          val name = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
          val updateName = { _name: String ->
               name.value = _name
          }

          val amount = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
          val updateAmount = { _amount: String ->
               amount.value = _amount
          }

        
          LazyColumn{
             item {
                  TextFieldsToExperiment(
                       name = name.value,
                       updateName = updateName,
                       amount = amount.value,
                       updateAmount = updateAmount
                  )
             }
          }

     }
}
```

And most importantly add this to your activity in the manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: you can declare mutable state as `val (name, updateName) = ...` instead of those lambdas you're creating manually.

Comment: I try this implementation, however the `focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)`  stop working and the field still not moving

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add this
`window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)`
after `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

did you try `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` it moves the window up so that your textfield became visible